Excel VBA Type-mismatch Date & Range
I am having trouble looping this data and wondering if you could give some advice.
Please help why am I still getting type mismatch.

My purpose is to extract the first and last entries for each day.
In excel, I have tried using the function LARGE and SMALL to determine the first time of the day and Last time of the day. However, before I am able to use the function, an error with type mismatch occurs.

Run-time error '13'
Type mismatch

Example: for 1 Aug 2024, only 7:27am and 5:38pm then follow by 2 Aug 2024, 7:34 and 05:44pm
Had tried using the function CDate and Dim my range of date as dim.

Post codes as text instead of image. firstDate=Datelist will always fail. You need to iterate all cell in range and compare with `firstDate.

Are you looking for VBA-only solution?

You're attempting to load an array of cell values into a date variable.
Loading them into an array held in a variant means the entire process can be significantly faster than reading each cell's value. When testing, I found 1m rows takes around 1/10th of a second, vs 1 whole second if scanning cell values.
Try this:
Sub testing2()

    Dim dateList As Variant
    Dim firstDate As Date
    newLR = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    firstDate = #1/8/2024#
    
    dateList = Sheet5.Range("a1:a" & newLR).Value
    
    For x = 1 To newLR
        If firstDate = dateList(x, 1) Then
            Debug.Print "Good record at row " & x
        End If
    Next x

End Sub


Iterate all date cells and compare with firstDate .
Sub CompareDate()
Dim dateList As Range, rng As Range
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim lr As Long
    
    lr = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    firstDate = #1/8/2024#
    
    Set dateList = Sheet5.Range("A1:A" & lr)
    
    For Each rng In dateList
        If firstDate = rng Then
            Debug.Print "Good row " & rng.Row
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub

